# Codeigniter 3 Registration and Login System

Tags: beginner, php, security, authentication, codeigniter

I am working on a basic blog application in **Codeigniter 3.1.8** and **Bootstrap 4**.

The application allows Registration and Login. I have concerns about the security level of the Registration system I have put together.

The Register controller:

```
class Register extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index() {
        $data = $this->Static_model->get_static_data();
        $data['pages'] = $this->Pages_model->get_pages();
        $data['tagline'] = 'Want to write for ' . $data['site_title'] . '? Create an account.';
        $data['categories'] = $this->Categories_model->get_categories();

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name', 'First name', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('last_name', 'Last name', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|trim|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|min_length[6]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('cpassword', 'Confirm password', 'required|matches[password]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('terms', 'Terms and Conditions', 'required', array('required' => 'You have to accept the Terms and Conditions'));
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="error-message">', '</p>');

        // If validation fails
        if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {
            $this->load->view('partials/header', $data);
            $this->load->view('auth/register');
            $this->load->view('partials/footer');
        } else {
            // If the provided email does not already
            // exist in the authors table, register user
            if (!$this->Usermodel->email_exists()) {
                // Encrypt the password
                $enc_password = md5($this->input->post('password'));

                // Give the first author admin privileges
                if ($this->Usermodel->get_num_rows() < 1) {
                    $active = 1;
                    $is_admin = 1;
                } else {
                    $active = 0;
                    $is_admin = 0;
                }

                // Register user
                $this->Usermodel->register_user($enc_password, $active, $is_admin);

                if ($this->Usermodel->get_num_rows() == 1) {
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('user_registered', "You are now registered as an admin. You can sign in");
                } else {
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('user_registered', "You are now registered. Your account needs the admin's aproval before you can sign in.");
                }
                redirect('login');
            } else {
                // The user is already registered
                $this->session->set_flashdata('already_registered', "The email you provided already exists in our database. Please login.");
                redirect('login');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Usermodel model:

```
class Usermodel extends CI_Model {

    public function email_exists() {    
        $query = $this->db->get_where('authors', ['email' => $this->input->post('email')]);
        return $query->num_rows() > 0;
    }

    public function get_num_rows() {
        $query = $this->db->get('authors');
        return $query->num_rows(); 
    }

    public function getAuthors(){
        $query = $this->db->get('authors');
        return $query->result();
    }

    public function deleteAuthor($id) {
        return $this->db->delete('authors', array('id' => $id));
    }

    public function activateAuthor($id) {
        $author = null;
        $updateQuery = $this->db->where(['id' => $id, 'is_admin' => 0])->update('authors', array('active' => 1));
        if ($updateQuery !== false) {
        $authorQuery = $this->db->get_where('authors', array('id' => $id));
        $author = $authorQuery->row();
        }
        return $author;
    }

    public function deactivateAuthor($id) {
        $author = null;
        $updateQuery = $this->db->where(['id' => $id, 'is_admin' => 0])->update('authors', array('active' => 0));
        if ($updateQuery !== false) {
            $authorQuery = $this->db->get_where('authors', array('id' => $id));
            $author = $authorQuery->row();
        }
        return $author;
    }

    public function register_user($enc_password, $active, $is_admin) {
        // User data
        $data = [
            'first_name' => $this->input->post('first_name'),
            'last_name' => $this->input->post('last_name'),
            'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
            'password' => $enc_password,
            'register_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'active' => $active,
            'is_admin' => $is_admin
        ];
        return $this->db->insert('authors', $data);
    }

    public function user_login($email, $password)
    {
        $query = $this->db->get_where('authors', ['email' => $email, 'password' => md5($password)]);
        return $query->row();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I have decided to post the `login()` method, from the Login controller, as changing the `Register` class would require changing the login accordingly:

```
public function login() {  
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|trim|valid_email');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="error-message">', '</p>');
    if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
      $email = $this->input->post('email');
      $password = $this->input->post('password');
      $this->load->model('Usermodel');
      $current_user = $this->Usermodel->user_login($email, $password);
        // If we find a user
      if ($current_user) {
        // If the user found is active
        if ($current_user->active == 1) {
          $this->session->set_userdata(
           array(
            'user_id' => $current_user->id,
            'user_email' => $current_user->email,
            'user_first_name' => $current_user->first_name,
            'user_is_admin' => $current_user->is_admin,
            'user_active' => $current_user->active,
            'is_logged_in' => TRUE
            )
           );
          // After login, display flash message
          $this->session->set_flashdata('user_signin', 'You have signed in');
          //and redirect to the posts page
          redirect('/dashboard');  
        } else {
          // If the user found is NOT active
          $this->session->set_flashdata("login_failure_activation", "Your account has not been activated yet.");
          redirect('login'); 
        }
      } else {
        // If we do NOT find a user
        $this->session->set_flashdata("login_failure_incorrect", "Incorrect email or password.");
        redirect('login'); 
      }
    }
    else {
      $this->index();
    }
  }
```

Looking for feedback and improvement ideas.

Comment: I just happened to open this question. So it's not a complete review. Instead of making `email_exists()` you can add this rule `is_unique[authors.email]` in your validation. You should not use `md5` for encrypting password. Use `password_hash()`.

Comment: Since you have added the `Login` controller could you please add the `index()` function for that class too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of things I'd do differently and the first is a **must**.

First, using `md5()` to encode a password is universally considered a bad practice. It's been considered too weak for that purpose since at least 2004 if not earlier. Instead, use the PHP function [password_hash](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php).

I would encrypt the password in the model. In fact, I'd move almost all the registration logic to the model. Here's my version of `Usermodel::register_user()`

```
public function register_user()
{
    // Get the entire $_POST array with one call then extract what we need
    $posted = $this->input->post();

    $field_list = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password'];
    foreach($field_list as $field){
        $data[$field] = $posted[$field];
    }

    $enc_password = password_hash($data['password']);

    // if password_hash fails it's time to bail
    if( ! $enc_password)
    {
        return false;
    }
    // update $data with encrypted password
    $data['password'] = $enc_password;

    // Put additional items in the $data array   
    $data['register_date'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    // CodeIgniter has a method to count records - use it. Remove get_num_rows() from model
    $data['is_admin'] = $this->db->count_all('authors') === 0 ? 1 : 0;
    $data['active'] = $data['is_admin'];

    if($inserted = $this->db->insert('authors', $data) === TRUE)
    {
        if($data['is_admin'] === 1)
        {
            $msg = "You are now registered as an admin. You can sign in";
        }
        else
        {
            $msg = "You are now registered. Your account needs the admin's approval before you can sign in.";
        }
        $this->session->set_flashdata('user_registered', $msg);
    }
    return $inserted;
}
```

With that new method and a little rearranging in the controller, we can make the code a bit more concise

```
public function index()
{
    $this->form_validation
        ->set_rules('first_name', 'First name', 'required')
        ->set_rules('last_name', 'Last name', 'required')
        ->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|trim|valid_email')
        ->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|min_length[6]')
        ->set_rules('cpassword', 'Confirm password', 'required|matches[password]')
        ->set_rules('terms', 'Terms and Conditions', 'required',
            array('required' => 'You have to accept the Terms and Conditions'))
        ->set_error_delimiters('<p class="error-message">', '</p>');

    if($this->form_validation->run())
    {
        // If the provided email isn't on record then register user
        if( ! $this->Usermodel->email_exists())
        {
            // Register user
            if($this->Usermodel->register_user())
            {
                // worked - go to login
                redirect('login');
            }
            // register_user() returned false - set an error message for use in 'auth/register' view
            $data['registration_error_msg'] = "Registration Failed! Please contact Administrator.";
        }
        else
        {
            // The user is already registered
            $this->session->set_flashdata('user_registered',
                "The email you provided already exists in our database. Please login.");
            redirect('login');
        }
    }

    // Validation or registration failed or it's the first load of this page
    $data = $this->Static_model->get_static_data();
    $data['pages'] = $this->Pages_model->get_pages();
    $data['tagline'] = 'Want to write for '.$data['site_title'].'? Create an account.';
    $data['categories'] = $this->Categories_model->get_categories();
    $this->load->view('partials/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('auth/register');
    $this->load->view('partials/footer');
}
```

Using `password_hash()` means the login logic needs to be refactored also and the PHP function `password_verify()` must be used. `password_verify` — confirms that a password matches a hash of that password. With that in mind, `Usermodel::user_login might look like this.

```
public function user_login()
{
    $email = filter_var($this->input->post('email'), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);

    if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
    {
        $user = $this->db
            ->select('password, user_id, active')
            ->get_where('authors', ['email' => $email])
            ->row();

        if(password_verify($this->input->post('password'), $user->password))
        {
            if($user->active)
            {
                return $user->user_id;
            }
            $this->session->set_flashdata("login_failure_activation", "Your account has not been activated yet.");
        }
        else
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata("login_failure_incorrect", "Incorrect email or password.");
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

The above is going to mean that the controller's `login()` method will need to be reworked too.

An unbreakable security rule is **"Never Trust User Input!"**

So, any data sent to the server must be sanitized and validated. This is true even for some identifier (like a user_id) that is part of a URL that you put on the screen. With that in mind, you should always (at the very minimum) make sure that any model function that has a `$id` argument is getting the right datatype.

Let's assume your user_id type is an integer. For instance, the controller method that activates an author might make this kind of check before sending it to the model.

```
public function activate_author($id)
{
    if(filter_var($id, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)) 
    {
        $this->Usermodel->activateAuthor($id)
        // other code 
    } 
    else 
    {
       //respond in a way that doesn't give a bad-actor too much info
    }

}
```

While CodeIgniter's validation library is quite good it doesn't go far enough. Particularly when it comes to sanitizing. A serious study of the [PHP docs on Filters](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php) is recommended. There are lots of online tutorials on using `filter_var` too.

Further Reading on PHP Security:

[A Gentle Introduction to Application Security](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/08/gentle-introduction-application-security)

[The 2018 Guide to Building Secure PHP Software](https://paragonie.com/blog/2017/12/2018-guide-building-secure-php-software)

[Checklist-Driven Security Considered Harmful](https://paragonie.com/blog/2017/04/checklist-driven-security-considered-harmful)

[Implementing Secure User Authentication in PHP Applications with Long-Term Persistence](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/04/secure-authentication-php-with-long-term-persistence)

Comment: Thanks for the elaborated answer. Please provide one for **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57646370/codeigniter-application-how-can-i-display-pagination-as-json)** question too.

Comment: Registration with `password_hash` works fine but my login function does no work, even though I replaced `md5()` with `password_hash`: `public function user_login($email, $password){
  $query = $this->db->get_where('authors', ['email' => $email, 'password' => $hashed_password]);
  return $query->row();
 }`

In the Login controller:  $hashed_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

What shall I change?

Comment: @RazvanZamfir I have added code showing how to check against a `password_hash()` value.

Comment: The first that registers as author must be automatically active, therefore he/she mist not see the "Your account has not been activated yet." message.

Comment: The first that registers **is** made active automatically.  `user_login()` will also set the "not activated yet" message.

Answer (score 0):

[DFriend's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/227249/200133) is good, but it sounds like some more clarity is needed about how to use the built-in `password_hash` function, and there are some architectural things you could improve.

Is the email address the primary key for the `authors` table? That's not an excellent choice, but we'll roll with it.

To properly use [password_hash](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php), you must also use [password_verify and password_needs_rehash](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php). This means that you can't just re-hash the password and look for the hash in the database. You have to identify the user-row in the database, load the stored hash into the PHP layer, and check that against the provided password in question. I haven't tested the below, but it's more-or-less how I'd write it.

```php
class Password_helper {
  const ALGO =  PASSWORD_DEFAULT;

  public static set_password(CI_Controller $CI, string $email, string $p):bool{
    // We could do any password-strength rules or setting of optional arguments here,
    // but I'll assume you're not doing that.
    return $CI->db->update(
      'authors',
      ['password' => password_hash($p, self::ALGO)],
      ['email' => $email]);
  }

  public static check_and_upkeep(CI_Controller $CI, string $email, string $p):bool{
    $_user = $CI->db->get_where(
      'authors',
      ['email' => $email], 
      1)
      ->result();
    if($_user){
      $user = $_user[0];
      if(password_verify($p, $user->password)){
        if(password_needs_rehash($user->password, self::ALGO)){
          self::set_password($CI, $email, $p);
        }
        return true;
      }
      else{
        return false;
      }
    }
    else{
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

The above might not jive perfectly with the concept of a "model" you're using; CodeIgniter's "model" concept is frankly problematic. Also, to use the above, you'll need to insert the user to the database *first*, then set their password. That's fine; you can just temporarily set their password to "".

#### Another security detail:

The business of making the first author the (an?) administrator is not good. There's hypothetically a chance someone might snipe you, and anyway it'll be cluttering up the codebase forever.
Depending what you mean by "admin", you maybe shouldn't even have "admins" in the same table as "users". In any case, remove that whole business from the registration stack; you can set your first admin manually in the database using some other tool.

#### Other stuff:

- A key and specific role of the Controller "endpoint" function (`index()` for example) is to parse, sanitize, and validate input, all of it. Both you and DFriend are reading `POST` values down in the model layer; those values should be passed down as arguments. If the number of arguments starts to feel unworldly, you can make classes ("models") for different data structures like Authors.
- I imagine you've repeated that trio of `$this->load->view()` calls, and the associated construction of `$data`, several times throughout your site. Wrap all of that up in a single place, either as a method of a Controller base class, or as a method of a Loader extension class. Also note that you can load views from inside of views, so a single master-template may be better than having separate header and footer "partial" views.
- Similar to what I mentioned above, don't use `$this->Usermodel->get_num_rows() == 1` to check if the user is an admin or is active; at that point you should have the user's data on hand and be able to check literally.
- I don't like flashdata, I'd rather use the url hash to pass a narrow range of messages to javascript running on the target page. But that's just personal preference.
- You could consolidate your (de)activateAuthor functions if you want. When they're called, you should have already validated that the target exists, so getting a falsy value from the DB would be grounds to throw an error.
- As much as I hate CI's "models", they'll be slightly less painful if you throw them all in your auto-load config file; then you don't need to load them explicitly.
- Your `login()` endpoint method calls the `index()` endpoint method if validation fails. That's an odd choice.
- Using typed function signatures will make your code easier to read and *more* likely to break in obvious ways. The advantage being that it's *less* likely to break in *insidious* ways. **I strongly recommend this.**
- In DFriend's code:

  - `$inserted` is assigned a value in the conditional of an if statement. Don't do that.
  - Don't rely on `redirect` or `load->view()` to stop execution. Even when it works it makes things harder to read. Use explicit return statements, or put the alternate path in an explicit `else`, or both.

#### Edit: Hi DFriend!

You raise several points; it sounded like you were hoping for a response.

- I like your point that brevity is part of clarity. The other point of clarity is saying what you mean, and saying it as code is briefer and stronger than leaving a comment.
- Sanitizing, validating, and parsing inputs isn't business logic, as I understand the phrase. *A* key role of the Controller is to handing inputs. If we take the framework for granted (as we would like to), then we conceptually enter the program in the Controller endpoint method. That method needs to know about inputs (POST values, query strings, url fragments, cookies) because that's where all further action will be directed from. The thing we can do to maintain separation of concerns is *make sure nobody else needs to read those input sources*.
- `redirect()` stops execution, but you have to know and remember that to make sense of code that relies on it. `CI->load->view()` doesn't stop execution, but is almost always the last call in the flow. Throwing a `return;` after all of them *is* a little verbose, but it's *clear*.
- It's a fact of life that there will be a lot of conditionals, and I really don't think there's a single pattern that will cover all cases. That said, if you're relying on a section of code only running if a prior `if` failed, *then you're in an else section whether you say so or not*.

Comment: Good call on keeping the encryption current through the use of `password_needs_rehash()`.

Comment: I disagree with the concept that the "key" role of a Controller is to "parse, sanitize, and validate input". Controllers are responsible for controlling the flow of the application execution and returning a response to requests - **not business logic**.

Comment: In the case of the Registration controller, ask the question: What does the controller need to know about the posted inputs? Such questions are vital to maintaining a clean Separation of Concerns. In this case, the controller doesn't need to know anything about the contents of `$_POST` other than checking that the basic requirements of the inputs are met (via `form_validation`)  and ready for processing by the business logic.

Comment: I agree that continually checking for the "first user" is begging for a different solution.

Comment: You said, "Your login() endpoint method calls the index() endpoint method if validation fails. That's an odd choice." I agree. That's why I asked the OP to include the code for that method.

Comment: You said, "$inserted is assigned a value in the conditional of an if statement. Don't do that." Why? It's very common syntax used to set a var and check its value. While there are cases where you can outsmart yourself by getting too clever that syntax if you stick to a single assignment and compare it works perfectly.

Comment: The CodeIgniter function `redirect()` _will always end code execution_. The last line of the function is `exit;`. Not sure what you're seeing that implies `load->view()` is assumed to end script execution. What am I missing?

Comment: Got to disagree that superflous `else` or redundant, or just plain unreachable `return` calls help readability or execution path comprehension. Deeply nested conditionals can make it just about impossible to tell what code will run, or when. They can also make it hard to keep code DRY. IMO, the more concise the code is the easier it is to read and the cleaner the execution path becomes.

Comment: Thanks @DFriend; I replied to a couple things as an edit above.